# Paginator not working properly while filtering the querysets?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Here filtering working fine and also paginator works fine on the first page. The issue is while going on the next page if it has any.It shows the remaining data on the next page but if I go on the next page then It displays 0 data.

Paginator doesnot working in the filter view only. So I think the issue is in this view only since I have the same template for search and list queryset view and in there the pagination works fine.

**EDIT:** I am using the same template with same context name for search, filter and list view but only in filter the pagination issue came.

search url looks like this

```
 (at first)  search/?q= and in the next page search/?page=2 while going previous page search/?page=1 # this works fine
```

While doing filter I expect the same but it is not working. In the filter/?page=2 there is no data.

views

```
def get(self, request):
    results = MyModel.objects.none()
    parameter = request.GET.get('param', '')
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    current_month = today.month
    past_7_days = today - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
    if parameter == '0':
        return redirect('show_all_querysets')
    elif parameter == '1':
        results = MyModel.objects.filter(datetime__date=today.date()).order_by('-datetime')
    elif parameter == '2':
        results = MyModel.objects.filter(datetime__range=[past_7_days, today]).order_by('-datetime')
    elif parameter == '3':
        results = MyModel.objects.filter(datetime__month=current_month).order_by('-datetime')
    querysets = Paginator(results, 10).get_page(request.GET.get('page'))
    return render(request, 'show_all_querysets.html', {'querysets': querysets})
```

Search View

```
 def get(self, request):
        q = request.GET.get('q', '')
        results = MyModel.objects.filter(message__icontains=q)).order_by('-datetime')
        querysets = Paginator(results, 10).get_page(request.GET.get('page'))
        return render(request, 'show_all_querysets.html', {'querysets': querysets})
```

template

```
 <div class="paginate-navigate ml-3">
                 {% if querysets.has_previous %}
                <a href="?{% if prev_url %}{{ prev_url }}{% endif %}page={{ querysets.previous_page_number}}">
                    <i title="previous" class="ic-chevron-left left"></i>
                </a>
                {% else %}
                <a disabled href="#">
                    <i class="ic-chevron-left left"></i>
                </a>
                {% endif %}

                {% if querysets.has_next %}
                <a href="?{% if prev_url %}{{ prev_url }}{% endif %}page={{ querysets.next_page_number}}">
                    <i title="next" class="ic-chevron-right right ml-2"></i>
                </a>
                {% else %}
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="ic-chevron-right right ml-2"></i>
                </a>
                {% endif %}

            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have both search fileter and pagination in query parameters then your url goes like `your_url/?params=some&page=2`

to achieve this first pass your `params` in `context`

```
return render(request, 'show_all_querysets.html', {'querysets': querysets,'parameter':parameter})
```

and then suppose you have previous and next buttons, so give href like this:

```
{% if querysets.has_previous %}
<a class="btn btn-outline-dark" href="{% if parameter %}{{ request.get_full_path }}&page={{ querysets.previous_page_number }}{% else %}?page={{ querysets.previous_page_number }}{% endif %}">Previous</a>
{% else %}
<button type="button" disabled class="btn btn-outline-dark" title = "No querysets available">Previous</button>
{% endif %}
{% if querysets.has_next %}
<a class="btn btn-outline-dark" href="{% if parameter %}{{ request.get_full_path }}&page={{ querysets.next_page_number }}{% else %}?page={{ querysets.next_page_number }}{% endif %}">Next</a>
{% else %}
<button disabled type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" title = "No querysets available">Next</button>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: edited my question.can you please look through this ?

Comment: but my answer would be same, If you have search query then pass it in template otherwise False

Comment: I got little confused why with the search view I didn't have to do pass the search query ?

Comment: in search view {'parameter':q} add this in context

Comment: I mean the pagination works fine in the search view without sending the param `q` but why it is not working with the filter view ? Isn't both the case are same?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217513/discussion-between-pruthvi-barot-and-user12428848).

Answer (score -1):

```
querysets = Paginator(results, 10).page(request.GET.get('page'))
```

Comment: While what you have written may answer the question, however it does seem a little lacking in [explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) and may illicit confusion to other users. Can you please expand upon your answer so that it is clearer and more accessible? This will make for better answers and help future users understand how the problem was solved.